# Auto posting to Facebook reaches far less people than manual posts

Tags: facebook

On our website we use an "auto post to Facebook and Twitter" plug-in. Once a post gets published with Wordpress, the plug-in automatically sends an update (a new post) to Facebook. However, in the admin panel of Facebook we clearly notice a difference in audience reach between manually typed posts into Facebook, and those auto posts. The automatic posts reach far less people.

Does anyone have any idea how this is possible, and how to by-pass this behaviour?

Comment: Removed [tag:wordpress] as questions about Worpress (WP, worpress.org) are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible because Facebook knows that it was an automated tool that did the post, and because Facebook sets the rules about what is shared with who.

By-pass it by disabling your plugin, and updating Facebook manually, tailoring the post for your Facebook audience.